# APK signature scheme v4 can't be verified with apksigner

Tags: android-11

I am trying out the [APK signature scheme v4](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/features#signature-scheme-v4) introduced in Android 11. I use the apksigner from the Android Sdk and it seems to work fine: it signs the .apk and generates the .idsig file as expected:

```
$ apksigner sign -v --ks ~/keystore.jks --ks-key-alias testkey app.apk
Keystore password for signer #1:
Signed

$ ls
app.apk  app.apk.idsig
```

However, when I use the same apksigner tool to verify the signature, it outputs the following:

```
$ apksigner verify -v ./app.apk
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
Verified for SourceStamp: false
Number of signers: 1
WARNING: META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/app-metadata.properties not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
... # and a bunch of other v1-related warnings
```

So it successfully verifies based on APK Signature Scheme v3 and doesn't take into account the .idsig at all (modifying the .idsig file does not affect the verification result).
I expect `Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4):` to also be `true`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

APK signature scheme v4 is a "detached signature format" which means the signature is saved in a separate file.

For apksigner you have to specify this detached signature file using the undocumented parameter `-v4-signature-file <idsig file>`.

So the full command for verifying an APK with detached v4 signature is:

```
apksigner verify -v -v4-signature-file <idsig file> <apk file>
```

The current version of apksigner seem to miss this option in the command help text but I am sure I had at least one version that already mentioned it (can't find it at the moment).

The parameter is e.g. mentioned in the [source code of apksigner](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/refs/heads/master/src/apksigner/java/com/android/apksigner/ApkSignerTool.java#476)